# Update plot based on user input in shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I have a shiny app that basically parses a user-uploaded `.txt` file (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47294192/upload-file-and-call-function-to-plot-data-in-shiny-app) I asked regarding the data input and parsing function), and then produces several plots by calling some plotting functions that are located above my `shinyServer` call in `server.R`.

**The functions called in my server.R script are:**

```
    parseR()      # Returns a dataframe (which is the result of parsing 
                    the user input entered in `fileInput) ([see here][1] for details) 
    senderPosts() # Returns a plot that is shown in tabPanel 1 
    wordFreq()    # Returns a plot that is shown in tabPanel 2
    chatCloud()   # Returns a  plot that is shown in tabPanel 3
```

I can successfully get the plot in tabPanel 1 to show the levels of a factor in the dataframe returned by parseR(), but I'm not sure how to use this to actually **update** the plot.

My question is, **how can I update a plot based on user input?**

Here is `server.R`:

```
shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

  data <- reactive({ 
    req(input$file1)

    inFile <- input$file1 

    df <- parseR(file=inFile$datapath) # Call my parser function 

    updateSelectInput(session, inputId = 'sender', label = 'Sender',
                      choices = levels(df$sender), selected = levels(df$sender))

    return(df)
  })

  # Main page
  output$contents <- renderTable({
    head(data(), 25)
  })

  # tabPanel 1
  output$postCount <-renderPlot({
    senderPosts(file=input$file1$datapath)

  })

  # tabPanel 2
  output$wordCount <-renderPlot({
    wordFreq(file=input$file1$datapath)

    })

  # tabPanel 3
  output$chatCloud <-renderPlot({
    chatCloud(file=input$file1$datapath)

  })

})
```

**ui.R**

```
library(shiny)

suppressMessages(library("wordcloud"))

shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel("File plotter"),
  tabsetPanel(
    tabPanel("Upload File",
             titlePanel("Upload your file"),
             sidebarLayout(
               sidebarPanel(
                 fileInput('file1', 'Select your file',
                           accept='.txt'
                           ),

                 tags$br()

               ),
               mainPanel(
                 tableOutput('contents'),
                 plotOutput('messageCount')
               )
             )
    ),

    # tabPanel 1 
    tabPanel("Post Count",
             pageWithSidebar(
               headerPanel('Number of posts per user'),
               sidebarPanel(

                 # "Empty inputs" - they will be updated after the data is uploaded
                 selectInput('sender', 'Sender', "")
               ),
               mainPanel(
                 plotOutput('postCount')
               )
             )
    ),

    # tabPanel 2 
    tabPanel("Word Frequency",
             pageWithSidebar(
               headerPanel('Most commonly used words'),
               sidebarPanel(

                 # "Empty inputs" - they will be updated after the data is uploaded
                 selectInput('word', 'Sender', "")
               ),
               mainPanel(
                 plotOutput('wordCount')
               )
             )
    ),

    # tabPanel 3
    tabPanel("Chat Cloud",
             pageWithSidebar(
               headerPanel('Most used words'),
               sidebarPanel(

                 # "Empty inputs" - they will be updated after the data is uploaded
                 selectInput('cloud', 'Sender', "")
               ),
               mainPanel(
                 plotOutput('chatCloud')
               )
             )
    )



  )
)
)
```

Comment: use the reactive value `data()` as the data argument passed to your plotting functions inside `renderPlot`. That will re-plot whenever `data()` is updated.

Comment: Render functions are normally reactive. That means whenever an input variable changes value within them. They should automatically be recalculated

Comment: Also, you don't want to have an update input function within an reactive function you better place that in a separate observe(Event) function.

Comment: @BertilNestorius - I'm not sure I understand. Would you be able to post a description as an answer (or a link to a description)?

Comment: @Nate - the data frame that I pass to the plot functions is produced by parseR(). I'm not sure how I can propagate my selections into the parseR() function. Totally confused!

Comment: just make your plotting functions take a data frame input, something like `senderPosts(data = data())`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as I mentioned first you don't want to keep the updateInput in the Reactive function. This is because reactives are lazy evaluation. They are better placed within a observer (`observe` or `observeEvent`) which are eager evaluation.

You can then get the value of the User input through `input$'inputId'`

I would also place the plot calculations in a reactive function but that is not necessary.

```
shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

  data <- reactive({ 
    req(input$file1)

    inFile <- input$file1 

    df <- parseR(file=inFile$datapath) # Call my parser function 

    return(df)
  })
  observe({
     df = data()
     updateSelectInput(session, inputId = 'sender', label = 'Sender',
                      choices = levels(df$sender), selected = levels(df$sender))
  })
  # Main page
  output$contents <- renderTable({
    head(data(), 25)
  })

  # tabPanel 1
  output$postCount <-renderPlot({
    senderPosts(file=input$file1$datapath,newParamter = input$sender)

  })

  # tabPanel 2
  output$wordCount <-renderPlot({
    wordFreq(file=input$file1$datapath)

    })

  # tabPanel 3
  output$chatCloud <-renderPlot({
    chatCloud(file=input$file1$datapath)

  })

})
```

Comment: I have adjusted my `shinySever` call as you suggest: `senderPosts(file=input$file1$datapath, user=input$sender)`, and my plot function now takes the `input$sender` : `senderPosts <- function(file_in='data/testChat.txt', user=NA){` and passes it to my parseR():
  `data <- parseR(file=file_in,user=user) ...` , which then filters the data frame based on this value, but It's still not working. Is this what you meant?

Comment: No, it's not working. When I isolate the two functions they run as expected and produce a plot filtered on `user='user'`, so it must be something happening in the `shinySever` call. Any ideas?

Comment: What do your  ui.r look like?

Comment: Ah - I've figured it out. Thanks for your help!